# PGTO formula in c#

Tags: c#, excel, finance

i need to use this formula in c#, and i dont know how is the original formula.
can anyone help me?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, and a Google search doesn't turn up anything that looks relevant. Can you give us some more details on what this formula is, represents, or describes?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/pt-pt/excel-help/pgto-HP005209215.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, Luis. And for the English speakers among us, here's the equivalent page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pgto-HP005209215.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PGTO is actually the Portuguese name for the PMT Excel function (found it out with this handy [Excel function names translation](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~trieschn/excel/excel.html)!

The `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace has the [Financial.PMT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.pmt.aspx) method, but of course you can use it in C#:

> Returns a Double specifying the
>   payment for an annuity based on
>   periodic, fixed payments and a fixed
>   interest rate

Comment: +1 for a nice answer. Just to add further clarification: No one should worry about using something from the `VisualBasic` namespace in C#. There's lots of handy functionality hidden there free for the taking, and you won't incur any performance or other penalties for using it. Just make sure you add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to your C# project.

Comment: never guess that was only for portugal, sorryabout that. thanks a lot that will help.